# Tic Tac Toe runs and functions completely, but after getting 3 in a row, another move has to be made for it to end

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

Is anyone of you able to find out why it loops around 1 extra time even though the while condition isn't true anymore?

**NOTE**: I have no clue if this is the right way of doing stuff on here, but here's the code. My code also isn't the most optimized, as I was planning on doing that after I got stuff working, but, well, that isn't the case right now.

```
import nl.saxion.app.SaxionApp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Application implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SaxionApp.start(new Application(), 650, 500);
    }

    public void run() {
        // Game Size
        int sizeInput = boardSize(); // Call method "boardSize()"

        if (sizeInput < 50) {
            sizeInput = 50;
            SaxionApp.printLine("Input too low, defaulted to min(50)");
        } else if (sizeInput >90) {
            sizeInput = 90;
            SaxionApp.printLine("Input too high, defaulted to max(90)");
        }

        int absoluteWidth = sizeInput*7;
        int absoluteHeight = sizeInput*7;
        SaxionApp.resize(absoluteWidth, absoluteHeight);

        int celWidth = absoluteWidth/5;
        int celHeight = absoluteHeight/5;

        int fontSize = celHeight / 3;

        ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        setFields(cells);

        String cell1 = cells.get(0);
        String cell2 = cells.get(1);
        String cell3 = cells.get(2);
        String cell4 = cells.get(3);
        String cell5 = cells.get(4);
        String cell6 = cells.get(5);
        String cell7 = cells.get(6);
        String cell8 = cells.get(7);
        String cell9 = cells.get(8);


        // Game over code
        boolean gameOver = false;
        // Winconditions
        String playerSymbol = "";

        int activePlayer = 1;
        int playerMove = 0;

        while (!gameOver){
            drawBoard(celWidth, celHeight, fontSize, cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9);



            SaxionApp.print("Player " + playerSymbol + ", make your move(1-9)?");
            playerMove = SaxionApp.readInt();


            if (activePlayer == 1 && !gameOver) {
                // Player 1 turn
//                SaxionApp.print("Player X, make your move(1-9)?");
//                playerMove = SaxionApp.readInt();

                activePlayer = 2;

                if (playerMove == 0) {

                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("Thank You For User Our App! :D");
                } else if (cells.get(playerMove-1).equals("O") || cells.get(playerMove-1).equals("X")) {
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("This cell has already been chosen, pick another!");
                    activePlayer = 1;

                } else if (playerMove == 1) {
                    cell1 = "X";
                    cells.set(0, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 2) {
                    cell2 = "X";
                    cells.set(1, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 3) {
                    cell3 = "X";
                    cells.set(2, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 4) {
                    cell4 = "X";
                    cells.set(3, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 5) {
                    cell5 = "X";
                    cells.set(4, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 6) {
                    cell6 = "X";
                    cells.set(5, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 7) {
                    cell7 = "X";
                    cells.set(6, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 8) {
                    cell8 = "X";
                    cells.set(7, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 9) {
                    cell9 = "X";
                    cells.set(8, "X");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                playerSymbol = "O";

                /*else if (playerMove == 0) {
                    i = 9;
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("Thank You For User Our App! :D");
                }*/

            } else if (activePlayer == 2 && !gameOver){
                // Player 2 turn
//                SaxionApp.print("Player O, make your move(1-9)?");
//                playerMove = SaxionApp.readInt();

                activePlayer = 1;

                if (playerMove == 0) {

                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("Thank You For User Our App! :D");
                } else if (cells.get(playerMove-1).equals("X")) {
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("Player X has already chosen this, pick another!");
                    activePlayer = 2;

                } else if (playerMove == 1) {
                    cell1 = "O";
                    cells.set(0, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 2) {
                    cell2 = "O";
                    cells.set(1, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 3) {
                    cell3 = "O";
                    cells.set(2, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 4) {
                    cell4 = "O";
                    cells.set(3, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 5) {
                    cell5 = "O";
                    cells.set(4, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 6) {
                    cell6 = "O";
                    cells.set(5, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 7) {
                    cell7 = "O";
                    cells.set(6, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 8) {
                    cell8 = "O";
                    cells.set(7, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                else if (playerMove == 9) {
                    cell9 = "O";
                    cells.set(8, "O");
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                }
                playerSymbol = "X";
            }

            ArrayList<Boolean> differentWins = winConditions(cells, playerSymbol);
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < differentWins.size()) {
                System.out.println("gameOver while works");
                if (differentWins.get(counter)) {
                    System.out.println("gameOver if works");
                    gameOver = true;
                    SaxionApp.clear();
                    SaxionApp.printLine("Player " + playerSymbol + " has won! Congratulations!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("gameOver if DOES NOT WORK");
                    counter++;
                }

            }

//            gameOver = true;

        }

        SaxionApp.printLine("Thank you for playing our game! :D");
        // Saving Image for easy preview
        SaxionApp.saveImage("Exercise4/end_test_output.png");

    }

    public int boardSize() {
        SaxionApp.print("What size do you wish the game window to be (min.50 and max.90)? ");
        int input = SaxionApp.readInt();
        SaxionApp.clear();
        return input;
    }

    private void drawBoard(int celWidth, int celHeight, int fontSize, String cell1, String cell2, String cell3, String cell4, String cell5, String cell6, String cell7, String cell8, String cell9) {
        SaxionApp.turnBorderOn();

        // Draw Board
        SaxionApp.drawLine(celWidth*2, celHeight, celWidth*2, celHeight*4);
        SaxionApp.drawLine(celWidth*3, celHeight, celWidth*3, celHeight*4);
        SaxionApp.drawLine(celWidth*1, celHeight*2, celWidth*4, celHeight*2);
        SaxionApp.drawLine(celWidth*1, celHeight*3, celWidth*4, celHeight*3);

        SaxionApp.turnBorderOff();

        // Draw Cell Values
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell1,celWidth*1+fontSize, celHeight+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell2,celWidth*2+fontSize, celHeight+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell3,celWidth*3+fontSize, celHeight+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell4,celWidth*1+fontSize, celHeight*2+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell5,celWidth*2+fontSize, celHeight*2+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell6,celWidth*3+fontSize, celHeight*2+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell7,celWidth*1+fontSize, celHeight*3+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell8,celWidth*2+fontSize, celHeight*3+fontSize, fontSize);
        SaxionApp.drawBorderedText(" "+cell9,celWidth*3+fontSize, celHeight*3+fontSize, fontSize);
    }

    public void setFields(ArrayList<String> cells) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            String cellNumber = String.valueOf(i);
            cells.add(cellNumber);
        }
        System.out.println(cells);
    }

    public ArrayList<Boolean> winConditions(ArrayList<String> cells, String playerSymbol) {

        boolean winConditionWidth1 = cells.get(0).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(1).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(2).equals(playerSymbol);
        boolean winConditionWidth2 = cells.get(3).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(4).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(5).equals(playerSymbol);
        boolean winConditionWidth3 = cells.get(6).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(7).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(8).equals(playerSymbol);

        boolean winConditionHeight1 = cells.get(0).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(3).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(6).equals(playerSymbol);
        boolean winConditionHeight2 = cells.get(1).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(4).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(7).equals(playerSymbol);
        boolean winConditionHeight3 = cells.get(2).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(5).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(8).equals(playerSymbol);

        boolean winConditionDiagonal1 = cells.get(0).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(4).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(8).equals(playerSymbol);
        boolean winConditionDiagonal2 = cells.get(2).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(4).equals(playerSymbol) && cells.get(6).equals(playerSymbol);

        ArrayList<Boolean>differentWins = new ArrayList<>();
        differentWins.add(winConditionWidth1);
        differentWins.add(winConditionWidth2);
        differentWins.add(winConditionWidth3);

        differentWins.add(winConditionHeight1);
        differentWins.add(winConditionHeight2);
        differentWins.add(winConditionHeight3);

        differentWins.add(winConditionDiagonal1);
        differentWins.add(winConditionDiagonal2);

        return differentWins;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code contains much repeated code. You should probably refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method `winConditions()` you pass `playerSymbol`, but before you pass it you always assign the other player symbol to it. So if it is player 1 turn ("X") you assign `playerSymbol` to be "O".

**Example: (E stands for empty)**

```
Turn 1
E|E|E
E|X|E
E|E|E

Turn 2
E|E|O
E|X|E
E|E|E

Turn 3
X|E|O
E|X|E
E|E|E

Turn 4
X|O|O
E|X|E
E|E|E

Turn 5
X|O|O
E|X|E
E|E|X
```

"X" won, right? But you're not checking if "X" won, you're checking if "O" won, because of the `playerSymbol = "O";` statement before calling `winConditions()`.
So that's why it takes one round longer. Next round you will set `playerSymbol` to "X" and this time a win will be detected.
Change the player symbol *after* checking for a win.

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix, yet for some reason that did not come to mind at all to be the problem. Might actually have looked over it by accident.

Thank you for the quick and incredibly clear explanation! Appreciate it!